# Show progress bar in a application showing db records

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jdbc

I have a application where i accept a number as input .and then use that to show up results on **another** page. The input number is used to hit multiple tables from an oracle db via sequential jdbc queries and it takes a *huge amount of time*(1-2 min) for results page to load.

I would assure that time is needed as i am fetching huge chunks of memo records , however i want a **progress bar** which would represent the progress by linking to no of jdbc queries done or maybe a simple **generic loading** screen until the results page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create DOM elements. All we need are two div elements, one in other. First one will be progress bar holder and you can put it whenever you want on your page. Another one is progress bar indicator. Something like this:

```
  <div id="progressBar"><div></div></div>
```

Now, we need some basic CSS for those elements. We will set width, height and colors:

```
#progressBar {
      width: 400px;
      height: 22px;
      border: 1px solid #111;
      background-color: #292929;
  }

 #progressBar div {
     height: 100%;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: right;
     line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
      width: 0;
      background-color: #0099ff;
     }
```

And at the end we need one function with 4 lines of code. It’s a simple function that    accept two parameters.

```
   function progress(percent, $element) {
   var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
   $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent+           "%&nbsp;");
```

}

First parameters is percentages that progress bar should show and other one is jQuery object of progress bar holder. If we want to set progress bar to 80% all we have to do is:

```
progress(80, $('#progressBar'));
```

Of course before all of this we need to include jQuery library on our page.

This simple progress bar can be easily styled with CSS. I’ve create a few skins that can be downloaded from GitHub. Feel free to create your own skins and send me pull request.